# How to use the --security-checks flag in trivy?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, containers, trivy

I am getting this error when using this flag **--security-checks**:

```
$ trivy --quiet image --security-checks .secrets  $TRIVY_ARGS $TRIVY_SCAN_IMAGE
2023-02-03T17:49:34.457Z    FATAL   flag error: scan flag error: unable to parse security checks: unknown security check: .secrets
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What I am trying to resolve is that I am getting an "**Asymmetric Private Key**" error because Trivy requires a private key when scanning secrets file.

```
================================================
Total: 1 (HIGH: 1, CRITICAL: 0)
HIGH: AsymmetricPrivateKey (private-key)
════════════════════════════════════════
Asymmetric Private Key
────────────────────────────────────────
 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key:1 (added by 'apt-get install -y  jq unzip python3-pan')
```

I am using [the Trivy documentation](https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.27.1/docs/secret/scanning/) to fix this error by adding this flag  **--security-checks**. [My initial code is this](https://gist.github.com/guinslym/c41614be3060c8f0bbd6ad7440a022fa#file-container-scanning-gitlab-ci-yml):

```
trivy --quiet image $TRIVY_ARGS $TRIVY_SCAN_IMAGE
```

I changed it to this:

```
trivy --quiet image --security-checks .secrets $TRIVY_ARGS $TRIVY_SCAN_IMAGE
```

I am getting this error:

```
$ trivy --quiet image --security-checks .secrets  $TRIVY_ARGS $TRIVY_SCAN_IMAGE
2023-02-03T17:49:34.457Z    FATAL   flag error: scan flag error: unable to parse security checks: unknown security check: .secrets
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I needed to add a valid parameter

```
trivy --quiet image --security-checks vuln $TRIVY_ARGS $TRIVY_SCAN_IMAGE
```